# Limit with lower-bound

Tags: limits, upper-lower-bounds

$$\lim _{n→∞}{\frac{\left\lfloor \sqrt{2n - 2}\right\rfloor}{2\sqrt{n}+\cos{n}}}$$
How can I calculate this limit? I can calculate it without the lower bound $\left(\frac{1}2\right)$ but do not know how to do it with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}-1}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\leq\frac{{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor}}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\leq \frac{\sqrt{2n-2}}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}-1}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor}}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n-2}}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{{\lfloor\sqrt{2n-2}\rfloor}}{2\sqrt{n}-\cos(n)}\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Via the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: But you can not do the third step when there is that lower bound no?

Comment: A lower bound on which quantity?

Comment: $\lfloor \sqrt{2n - 2}\rfloor != \sqrt{n}\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{2n - 2}}n\rfloor$
sorry not bound, floor

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)